# How does one complexify a real $n$-dimensional Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

If $V$ is a real vector space, then the **complexification** of $V$ is formally defined as $V^{\mathbb{C}}=V\otimes_{\mathbb{R}}\mathbb{C}$. Is there an analogous complexification operation for a real $n$-dimensional Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$?

*Idea:* The notion of complexification for Lie groups exists, so perhaps one can "complexify" a real Riemannian manifold by realizing it as a Lie group (or the quotient of one). It seems that under complexification of a real manifold some additional information must be added to determine a complex structure.

---

The reason I ask this is because I am looking through the Riemannian holonomy section of [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holonomy#Riemannian_holonomy) and it states that "the complexified holonomies $SO(n,\mathbb{C})$, $G_2(\mathbb{C})$, and $Spin(7,\mathbb{C})$ may be realized from complexifying real analytic Riemannian manifolds."

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Most manifolds are not quotients of Lie groups - how do you plan on complexifying those?  What properties do you want your complexification to have?

Comment: I would like to obtain a complexified holonomy for the holonomy group of $M$, e.g. if $Hol(M)=SO(n)$ then the complexified holonomy is $SO(n,\mathbb{C})$ which is realized by complexifiying the real analytic Riemannian manifold $M$. @JasonDeVito

Comment: Hm, I'm afraid I'm useless, except to say that if the complexification is a manifold, then generically the holonomy group is all of $SO(n)$.  So the complexification of a generic manifold will not be generic.

Comment: I think things are basically hopeless except in the case of symmetric spaces. Google "complexification symmetric space" for some results.

Comment: The reason I ask is because I am looking through the Berger classification section of [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holonomy#Riemannian_holonomy) and it states that "the complexified holonomies $SO(n, \mathbb{C}),$ $G_2(\mathbb{C}),$ and $Spin(7,\mathbb{C})$ may be realized from complexifying real analytic Riemannian manifolds." @JasonDeVito

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This answer was written by @M.G. on MO:

I believe the following is meant:

Every smooth (real) manifold $M$ has a (unique) real-analytic structure compatible with the smooth structure. So, cover $M$ with real-analytic charts, i.e. whose transition functions are real-analytic diffeomorphisms
$$
\phi_{ij}:=\phi_j^{-1}\circ\phi_i: U_{ij}:=\phi_i^{-1}(\phi_i(U_i)\cap\phi_j(U_j))\to U_{ji}
$$
One can find open subsets $U_i^{\mathbb{C}}\subseteq\mathbb{C}^n$ with $U_i^{\mathbb{C}}\cap\mathbb{R}^n=U_i$ and $U_{ij}^{\mathbb{C}}\cap\mathbb{R}^n=U_{ij}$ such that the (real-analytic) $\phi_{ij}$ extend to biholomorphisms $\phi_{ij}^{\mathbb{C}}:U_{ij}^{\mathbb{C}}\to U_{ji}^{\mathbb{C}}$ satisfying the usual cocycle conditions. Then the complexification $M^{\mathbb{C}}$ is defined as a quotient space of the disjoint union, $\left(\coprod_i U_i^{\mathbb{C}}\right)/\sim$, where $z_i\sim z_j$ iff $z_i\in U_{ij}^{\mathbb{C}}$ and $z_j = \phi_{ij}^{\mathbb{C}}(z_i)$ (this works because of the cocycle conditions). The maps $U_i^{\mathbb{C}}\hookrightarrow\coprod U_i^{\mathbb{C}}$ induce coordinate charts $U_i^{\mathbb{C}}\to M^{\mathbb{C}}$ with biholomorphic transition functions.

This and the details around it are part (of the proof of) Bruhat-Whitney's theorem* on the existence of $M^{\mathbb{C}}$. Moreover, complexification is functorial in the obvious way. By Grauert, $M^{\mathbb{C}}$ is in fact a Stein manifold.

*F. Bruhat and H. Whitney, Quelques propriétés fondamentales des ensembles analytiques-réels, Comment. Math. Helv. 33, 132-160 (1959).

Comment: Is the complexification so obtained unique in some way?

Comment: @AlexM. sorry for replying so late, I didn't get a notification and saw your comment accidentally by following the link from MO. Yes, there is uniqueness of the *germ* of $M$ in the following sense (btw, also part of Bruhat-Whitney's statement): if $N_1$ and $N_2$ are two complex manifolds containing $M$ as real-analytic and totally real submanifold with $\dim_\mathbb{C}N_1=\dim_\mathbb{C}N_2=\dim_\mathbb{R}M$, then some neighbourhoods of $M$ in $N_1$ and $N_2$ are biholomorphic.

Answer (score 0):

May be the following link help. The  construction gives also a  complex structure for the tangent bundle of  every real manifold.

https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-1-4757-9771-8_8#citeas