# What is the complexification of a 2-sphere?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, complex-geometry

Here, by 2-sphere I mean a normal sphere, which is a two-dimensional manifold embedded into the three-dimensional euclidean space.

Does such a complexification even exists?

Comment: What do you mean by "complexification"? Do you mean "How to see $S^2$ as a complex manifold"?

Comment: @Didier The likely interpretation is to complexify the tangent bundle (by complexifying each of the underlying vector spaces) and then ask if there's a complex manifold with that tangent bundle.

Comment: @MichaelBarz To me it is ambiguous. It can either refer to seeing the two-sphere as a complex curve, or seeing $TS^2\otimes \mathbb{C}$ as the tangent bundle of a manifold, which is not exactly the same thing. That is why I asked.

Comment: I have seen that for manifolds complexification can be defined by complexification of the local maps combined with analytic continuation of remapping functions. In particular, I saw this kind of definition in the answer to [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/306765/how-does-one-complexify-a-real-n-dimensional-riemannian-manifold-m-g).

Comment: @ГригорийСтарков If the question refers to a construction as in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2861793) then of course it can be applied to the two sphere, there is no big deal with it.

Comment: Yes, it refers to that construction. However, I am no specialist in differential geometry. Could someone tell me what the end result would be?

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\Cpx}{\mathbf{C}}\newcommand{\Proj}{\Cpx\mathbf{P}}$tl; dr: The complexification of the sphere (in the sense clarified in the comments) may be viewed as the complex quadric $\Proj^{1} \times \Proj^{1}$.

---

The sphere may be viewed as two copies of the real plane, with respective coordinates $(x, y)$ and $(u, v)$, and with the identification
$$
(u, v) = \frac{(x, -y)}{x^{2} + y^{2}}
$$
away from each copy of the origin.

To complexify, treat all variables as complex, with the same identification. Note, however, that $x^{2} + y^{2} = 0$ along two lines through the origin, $y = \pm ix$. That is, we're taking two copies of $\Cpx^{2}$, removing two lines in each ($y = \pm ix$ and $v = \pm iu$) to obtain two copies of $\Cpx^{\times} \times \Cpx^{\times}$, and identiying the complements via the preceding equation.

To see the identification clearly, it's convenient to make linear changes of change coordinates in $\Cpx^{2}$, writing
$$
\begin{aligned}
  x &= \tfrac{1}{2}(x' + y'), \\
  y &= \tfrac{1}{2}i(x' - y');
\end{aligned}\qquad
\begin{aligned}
  u &= \tfrac{1}{2}(u' + v'), \\
  v &= \tfrac{1}{2}i(u' - v').
\end{aligned}
$$
A short calculation gives $x^{2} + y^{2} = x'y'$, so
$$
u = \frac{x}{x^{2} + y^{2}} = \frac{1}{2}\biggl[\frac{1}{x'} + \frac{1}{y'}\biggr], \qquad
v = -\frac{y}{x^{2} + y^{2}} = \frac{i}{2}\biggl[\frac{1}{x'} - \frac{1}{y'}\biggr].
$$
That is, the identification on the two copies of $\Cpx^{2}$ is
$$
(u', v') = \biggl(\frac{1}{x'}, \frac{1}{y'}\biggr)
$$
off the unions of the coordinate axes. Consequently, the identification space is $\Proj^{1} \times \Proj^{1}$.

Comment: In other words, $S^2\times S^2$. I didn’t follow the commentary and thought quadric $\sum z_j^2=1$ in $\Bbb C^3$. Interesting.

Comment: @TedShifrin Embarrassingly, your insight was not my first thought: I was expecting the total space of $\mathcal{O}(2)$, or the second Hirzebruch surface after adding points at infinity. Getting the quadric was initially a surprise....